# Query to get foreign key PK

Tags: django

i am trying to carry out a check on the user once he want to go to the next page. the code will do a check on the User and its related model to see if the user has created the data. if it is created he will be redirected to next page else he will redirected to the create page. the similer query function will then be used to assign the other models foreign keys when form is being processed.

```
     class Startup ( models.Model ) :
         author = models.OneToOneField ( User , on_delete = models.CASCADE )
         startup_name = models.CharField ( 'Startup Name' , max_length = 32 , null = False , blank = False )

     @login_required
     def create_startupform(request) :
         q = User.objects.filter(Startup.startup_name.primary_key)
         if q.exists():
             return redirect ( 'str_detailedview' )
         else:
             form = startupform ( request.POST or None )
                 if form.is_valid ( ) :
                 instance = form.save (commit = False)
                 instance.author = request.user
                 instance.save()
                 return redirect ( 'str_detailedview' )
             else:
                 form = startupform()
             return render ( request , 'str_name.html' , { 'form' : form } )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line doesn't make any sense:

```
q = User.objects.filter(Startup.startup_name.primary_key)
```

If you want to check that a `Startup` object exists for a user, you can do that like this:

```
q = Startup.objects.filter(author=request.user)
```

Comment: works like a charm, one final question, can i use the same method to assign other models foreign key on create. i am also facing a challenge on query related foreign keys

Comment: This could be its own question, but yes, that should work for `ForeignKey` and `OneToOne` relationships, as long as the object you are assigning has been saved.

Comment: i have tried the same method with Foreign key but it didnt work, appreciate if you can assess in that and look at my question herehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/59227721/django-modal-submit-form-with-foreign-key-not-working?noredirect=1#comment104670058_59227721