# Django modal Submit form with foreign key not working

Tags: django, django-views, foreign-keys, bootstrap-modal

i have a model which is populated in a Bootstrap Modal, i am using class based view to render the form and submit it to the Database, however, when i click the save i get an error:

```
AttributeError at /create_startupaboutform/
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'Startup'
```

i am not sure if am assigning the FK correctly, however, for the Startup model it is working fine in function view but for class based view it is not. here is my code and i appreciate feedback on it.

model.py:

```
class Startup ( models.Model ) :
    author = models.OneToOneField ( User , on_delete = models.CASCADE )
    startup_name = models.CharField ( 'Startup Name' , max_length = 32 , null = False , blank = False )

class Startup_About ( models.Model ) :
    str_about = models.ForeignKey ( Startup , on_delete = models.CASCADE )
    about = models.TextField ( 'About Startup' , max_length = 2000 , null = False , blank = False )
    problem = models.TextField ( 'Problem/Opportunity' , max_length = 2000 , null = False , blank = False )
    business_model = models.TextField ( 'Business Monitization Model' , max_length = 2000 , null = False ,blank = False )
    offer = models.TextField ( 'Offer to Investors' , max_length = 2000 , null = False , blank = False )
```

forms.py:

```
class startupform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Startup
        fields = ('startup_name',)
        widgets = {
            'startup_name': forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class':'form-control'}),
        }

class startupaboutform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Startup_About
        fields = ('about','problem','business_model','offer','str_about',)
        widgets = {
            'about' : forms.Textarea ( attrs = { 'class' : 'form-control' } ) ,
            'problem' : forms.Textarea ( attrs = { 'class' : 'form-control' } ) ,
            'business_model' : forms.Textarea ( attrs = { 'class' : 'form-control' } ) ,
            'offer' : forms.Textarea ( attrs = { 'class' : 'form-control' } ) ,

        }
```

view.py:

```
decorators = [str_required, login_required]

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
@method_decorator(str_required, name='dispatch')
class create_startupaboutform(CreateView):
    template_name = 'create_about.html'
    form_class = startupaboutform
    success_url = '/str_detailedview/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.str_about = Startup_About.objects.filter(str_about=self.request.Startup)
        return super(create_startupaboutform, self).form_valid(form)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path ( 'appwizard/' , views.applicationwizard , name = 'appwizard' ) ,
    path ( 'create_startupform/' , views.create_startupform, name = 'create_startupform' ),
    path('create_startupaboutform/', views.create_startupaboutform, name='create_startupaboutform'),
      ]
```

Templates - HTML modal trigger button:

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">

</head>
<body>


<a href="#"  id="btn" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Open Modal</a>


{% include "create_about.html" %}


<script src="{% static 'assets/js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>

<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
             $("#btn").on("click", function(){
                 $("#form").load("/create_startupaboutform/", function(){
                 $("#about").modal("show");
             });
             });
     });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Templates - HTML modal form:

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="{% url 'create_startupaboutform' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
<div class="modal fade" id="about" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Title</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                        aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                {{form}}
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-light" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I think your form_valid not correct. You see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/

Comment: @ali Yaman i am following the documentation for modelform class based view, my Startup_About is linked to Startup model and am trying to assign it to the object startup name.....appreciate if you advise the change i have to do.

Comment: @PedramParsian, hi, no in my case it is a single form

Comment: i have added str_about to the modelform as a hidden fields but when i click save it redirect me to a page with form in it and error of hidden field required

Comment: @MohammadAlBlooshi Sorry about that; That was my mistake. Could you please include your templates as well? I think you have a `request.Startup` or something there that's causing the error.

Comment: @PedramParsian hi pedram, i have included my templates in the question, yes my issue is that str_about is a foreign key related Startup model as the user can only have one startup_name but am failing to properly assign it on form processing prior to committing the save

Comment: @Willwm Van Onsem appreciate your support to help me resolve this problem.